# Set Live Frame on Camera Capturing Image Android (Error)

Tags: image, camera, overlay, frame, implementation

I got an error when I implemented this code below.
I got an error on CameraActivity.java (please see my picture attachment) 
anyone can fix this?

this is CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private Camera camera = null;
    private SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView = null;
    private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
    private boolean previewing = false;

    private Display display = null;


    private static int wid = 0, hgt = 0;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    private View cameraViewControl = null;
    private ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = null;

    private Button btnCapture = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        wid = display.getWidth();
        hgt = display.getHeight();

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.cameraoverlay);

        cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceView);
        cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
        cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        layoutParamsControl = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        cameraViewControl = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cambutton,null);
        this.addContentView(cameraViewControl, layoutParamsControl);
        btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback,
                        cameraPictureCallbackRaw,
                        cameraPictureCallbackJpeg);
            }
        });
    }

    CameraSource.ShutterCallback cameraShutterCallback = new CameraSource.ShutterCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShutter()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    CameraSource.PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackRaw = new CameraSource.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {

        }


        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    CameraSource.PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new CameraSource.PictureCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {

        }


        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
            hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

            Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

            canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable
                    (R.drawable.frame);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, wid, hgt);
            drawable.draw(canvas);

            File storagePath = new File(Environment.
                    getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyCameraApp/");
            storagePath.mkdirs();

            File myImage = new File(storagePath,
                    Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

            try
            {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myImage);
                newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);


                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Log.d("In Saving File", e + "");
            }

            camera.startPreview();

            drawable = null;

            newImage.recycle();
            newImage = null;

            cameraBitmap.recycle();
            cameraBitmap = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width, int height)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(previewing)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }
        if (camera != null){
            try
            {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device camera is not working properly, please try after sometime.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }}
```

[this is an error on CameraActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1HGu.png)

This is cambutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cambutton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" /> </LinearLayout>
```

this is cameraoverlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraSurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/frame" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope anyone can fix this code...
I compile with android studio 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I can Fix,

I have Same Error, 
You Need to Import Right Camera Class(hardware.camera) , You implement Graphics class that's why.

Remove Camera Obj and re write And Select hardware.camera.

Comment: It's not the Camera here, but rather android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basic statement: Java is not a duck-type language. This means that if two classes, A and B, both define a method **foo()**, you cannot use an object of class B in the context that expects object of class A, even if you only execute **foo()** in that context.

Same is true for Java **interface**s. If two interfaces, **IA** and **IB**, both declare method **onShutter()**, and you have a class that implements **IA**, you cannot use it in context that expects objects that implements **IB**.

This is what, unfortunately, happened with Google camera APIs for Android. They define two similar interfaces, [ShutterCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.ShutterCallback.html) and [ShutterCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.ShutterCallback). They even have the same names, but they are different. The first *full name* is actually **android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback**, the latter **com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.ShutterCallback**.

The first interface is part of the *deprecated* Android Camera API. If you target Android platforms 21 (Lollipop) and higher, Google recommends to use the new [**camera2**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API.

The second interface is part of a [vision](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary) Google APIs for Android. This API is not intended to cover full Camera functionality. It provides easy wrappers for some camera-related detection tasks, e.g. barcode, or face detection.

Your code does not employ such detectors. Please note that the **vision** API does not expose many camera tuning controls, e.g. it does allow you to capture a picture, but [does not allow you to choose high picture resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187806/on-some-devices-google-mobile-visions-camerasource-returns-low-resolution-image). You will get even more control, and better performance, when you switch to **camera2** API (you can start with the official [basic sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)).

On the other hand, you can find the [CameraSource.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) and modify it as you wish.

To let your code with minimal change to your code, to let it work, **CameraSource.ShutterCallback** should be renamed to **Camera.ShutterCallback**; same for both **PictureCallback**s.

You probably have

```
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
```

by mistake.

Comment: can you tell more detail please

Comment: Let me make the short story long. See the updated answer.

Comment: http://i293.photobucket.com/albums/mm60/zalzondabuzz/Untitled_zpsb2uonfmy.png

here's an eror

Comment: Oh yeah , this is a source code, before I implemented into android studio,,,
may be you can give me a fix code on android studio...

http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.co.id/2013/05/set-live-frame-on-camera-capturing.html

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question now

Comment: I mean, I got that source from this blog : http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.co.id/2013/05/set-live-frame-on-camera-capturing.html

Comment: I mean, I got that source from this blog : http://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.co.id/2013/05/set-live-frame-on-camera-capturing.html

can you help me to fix that source code

Comment: I don't understand how that blog is related to your original question. And I don't know what fixes you expect for that code, I believe it works as is.